# How to perform User Migration?

Tags: migration

I'm looking for a method to export/import all my WP users + Existing passwords.

Answer (score 2):

use WordPress Duplicator plugin,

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

it will automatically transfer your Content, pages, posts, media files, users database, everything will be moved at once.

thanks, 
Muhammad

Comment: the challenge is that the new site currently has posts and users, and i need to replace all existing users + migrate a few newer ones. So the existing users should retain their post's associations. Will duplicator handle that?

Comment: yes, duplicator will basically create a complete backup package, then you can restore that package to anywhere, it would keep the users and their associated posts.

Comment: Can i just do this manually like this?

1. Export my old
`wp_usermeta , wp_users , and wp_options' tables

2. Remove my new
`wp_usermeta , wp_users , and wp_options' tables
 and import the new one i just exported

done

Comment: Well @Arturino, short answer no; you won't get the actual user-post assiciation if you dont copy over `wp_posts` too, since that's where `post_author` is located.  I'd copy `wp_postmeta` over too